# Using appcompat on version v17

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I have an implementetion of action bar in my project and I want it to work it on kitkat 4.4.*. But on my appcompat I have to set version to the lolipop and it all fails to prepare me a good app (maybe because my appcompat is v7). Do you know maybe what appcompat download, or how to change config for appcompat to work on older devices?

Sincerely Peter.

EDIT

When I try to build project targeted for v17 I get shitload of these:

```
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v11/themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v14/themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] 
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit] /home/oneat/android-workspace/appcompat/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-03-20 12:28:06 - Akshit]
```

So what is a problem? MAybe eclipse is one?

Comment: Do you have sdk 5.0 installed in sdk manager? Because that one is required to use new appcompact library.

Comment: I have, but I can use it on 5.0.1 but cant on older - however I have them installed.

Comment: It is app compact library made to run on older version see this [page](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: "it all fails to prepare me a good app" -- please explain what you mean by this. Your choice of `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., "Build Target" in Eclipse) does not have an impact on whether your app is "good" or not.

Comment: target=android-21
compileSdkVersion=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat
for app

target=android-21
compileSdkVersion=android-17
android.library=true
for library

now it compiles but doesnt run on mobile.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't run on mobile? Is it crashing? If yes then post log cat. @oneat

Comment: Keep Build Target version to 21. It will work fine on v17. @oneat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat v21, you **have to** compile your project with API 21. Use:

`compileSdkVersion 21`